# How to redirect to a parent route from a children component in angular9?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, router-outlet

i have the next routing config

```
 const appRoutes: Routes = [


 {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'Home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'Clients', component: ClientsComponent},
  {path: 'Client', component: ClientComponent,children:[
      {path:'Home',redirectTo:'Home',pathMatch:'full'},
      {path:'Files',component: FilesComponent,},
      {path:'Contacts',component:ContactsComponent}
    ],},
  {path: 'Users', component: UsersComponent},
  {path: 'User', component: UserComponent},
  {path: '**', component:HomeComponent}
]
```

and i have a couple of routeroutlets one in the app.component.html and the second one in another componente that looks like this

```
<app-client-menu></app-client-menu>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

from the client-menu i want to redirect  to home page that renders in app.component.hmtl in this way

```
<ul class="sidenav sidenav-fixed" id="mobile">
  <li>
    <div>
      <div class="background">
        <img src="assets/images/clientsBanner.jpg" class="responsive-img" alt="empleados">
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a [routerLink]="['Files']">Files</a></li>
  <li><a [routerLink]="['Contacts']">Contacts</a></li>
  <li><a >Update Client</a></li>
  <li><a >Delete Client</a></li>
  <li><a [routerLink]="[ { outlets: {home:['Home'] } }]"><i class="material-icons green-text ">home</i>Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

but when i do that i endup going to not found page and with this url looking like Client/Files/Home insted of /Home how could i solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have Home defined as both a child route and a top route.  I assume the intention was to have the home link in the child route redirect to the top route?

if so, this is unnecessary.

Remove the child Home route and change the router link to

homeHome

Comment: this worked it seems somehow having both routes confused the router thanks

Comment: It's not that the two routes confused it because you can absolutely have a Home route at multiple levels, it's more that your child home route was redirecting to itself rather than down a level.  By changing the link in the child component, you're telling the router to look one level up for the route with the home path rather than in the same "folder"

Answer (score 1):

You can move "backward" adding `../` just like you can use it in `cmd`. So in your case, it will be something like this:

```
  <li><a routerLink="../Home">Home</a></li>
```

If you would like to use arrays, it might be looks like this:

```
 <li><a [routerLink]="['../','Home']">Home</a></li>
```